# How set Authorization attribute role MVC4 to the user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I'm trying to use the Authorize attribute on MVC 4 application,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Super-User")]
public JsonResult Remove(int id)
{
      .
      .
      .
}
```

I know that only the roles "Administrator" and "Super-User" roles are authorized to execute the method `Remove`, but how I can set the role to the actual User of the application?

Comment: What authentication system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Add the current user to a role using

`Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[]{HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name}, "Admin");`

Roles class is available in System.Web.Security namespace.

if you want  to add users and Roles 
-Open your solution in Visual Studio
 goto project->ASP.NET configuration->Security Tab

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - somehow, so that `HttpContext.Current.User` is set and the `IsInRole` method returns true.

The easiest way to do this would be to follow one of built-in mechanisms of authentication/authorization: Forms authentication or Windows authentication.

The former requires that the request carries a valid forms cookie issued by the server. The latter requires that the request principal can be authenticated in the domain controller.

You are however free to implement a custom authentication module.

If you are just starting to learn this, probably you'd like to use Forms Authentication for this. Just let your users log in, issue the cookie and the cookie will automatically be carried by subsequent ajax request (assuming your server code is called from within javascript client-side ajax call).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a user to roles using a Role Provider.

```
var rolesProvider = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
```

Check the role exists

```
if (!rolesProvider.RoleExists("SuperUser"))
{
    rolesProvider.CreateRole("SuperUser");
}
```

Check if the user is in the role already, if not, add the user to the role

```
if (! rolesProvider.IsUserInRole("JohnSmith", "SuperUser"))
{
    rolesProvider.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"JohnSmith"}, new[] {"SuperUser"});
}
```